# why -5//2 gives -3 in python3 Not -2

Tags: python, c++, division

I always thought '//' in python is same as '/' in c++.
if I do cout<<-5/2; in c++, it gives -2. But in python if I try print(-5//2) it gives -3. why is this happening? aren't they both the same.?

Comment: You have encountered one of the ways they are not exactly the same. Yes, in Python `//` will perform integer division, but Python's behavior for rounding negative numbers differs from C++'s. In general there are very few things in programming languages that are *exactly* the same as things in other programming languages.

Comment: If the results are different, they are clearly not the same.

Comment: C++ rounds integer division towards 0, producing `-2`.  Python rounds toward -infinity, producing `-3`.  Neither language "gives 3".

Comment: Python's '//' operator performs "floor division", not "integer division". Simple as that.

Comment: Also "What's the mathematical reason behind Python choosing to round integer division toward negative infinity?" is a good example of the Bulverism fallacy (in that this is not what is happening, so assuming it is and then asking 'why' is fallacious). The linked answer is not a good answer.

Comment: The equivalent in Python is: print(math.trunc(-5 / 2))

Comment: *why is this happening?* Because what you had always thought was actually mistaken.  *aren't they both the same?*  No, as empirically demonstrated.

Comment: I am tempted to answer: because Python is 20 years younger than C, so it fixes some conceptual mistakes from earlier languages.